# Eclipse - Opening resource (a file) in closed project

Tags: eclipse

I am looking for a plugin or some kind of feature to open a resource file in open and closed projects. Eclipse seems to only search in opened projects. Could anyone suggest one.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this with Eclipse API. Eclipse won't create the necessary data structures for closed projects.